How to make an animation of fabric folding?
I need to make an animation of a poster with some sort of design unfolding on a large building.
I suspect I need to first roll up the fabric using sculpting, however I can't figure out how to do it decently and add keyframes. I'm new to this area.



Hello, please use english, as for your question, do you have an image of how your cloth is supposed to be before unfolding?

I added a photo. Something like this, but more neat and condensed

You could do it in Sculpt mode, choose the Pose brush, set it to Deformation Target > Cloth Simulation, Deformation > Squash & Stretch:

Sculpt:

You can scale it a bit on Z in Edit mode. To make it unfold like a fabric, first thing assign the top edge loop to a vertex group (CtrlG):

Give a Cloth simulation to the object, choose the vertex group as Pin Group, enable Self Collisions:

Result (if there's a wall behind, give this wall a Collision simulation):

To delay the simulation, change the Simulation Start under Cache. Once you're glad, click on Bake:


Thank you! How can I add keyframes to make it straighten out at the end?

you can't keyframe sculpt deformation out of the box, but why not add a cloth simulation once you deformed the plane like explained in the answer? it would do the deformation for you

assign the top edge loop to a vertex group, give a Cloth simulation to the object and in the Cloth panel > Shape > select the pin group so that the object hangs from this edge

I've edited, I hope it helps

Thanks a lot!!!
